# Mounting a macOS disk image in Linux

Tags: linux, mount, hfs+

I have a disk image of an SSD drive with macOS with a partition containing an HFS+ filesystem and I want to mount it in Linux. How could it be achieved?

Comment: It's almost certainly HFS+ (and not HFS) if the macOS that created that file system was released after 1988. Note that more modern MacOS then ca 2017 uses a different filesystem, APFS.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, on desktop Linuxes, it's quite straightforward to access whole-disk file system images;

```bash
udisksctl loop-setup -f /path/to/your/disk/image
```

should be able to detect all GPT partitions on the image, and offer them as devices you can click on in your file manager, to mount them.

It's been years for me, but I remember the Linux HFS+ driver to be quite usable, so you probably have to do nothing else.

Comment: That's not surprising  as you said this was a disk image, not a partition image.